# How to track time spent on online PDF file viewed by user? (PDF file as shown in image)

Tags: javascript, c#

I have tried for time spent on a web page. Now I want to track the time spent by user on pdf.
The code I used is as below:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" />
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    hid_Ticker.Value = TimeSpan.Parse(hid_Ticker.Value).Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)).ToString();
    lit_Timer.Text = "Time spent on this page: " + hid_Ticker.Value.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: And what was the result? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: What's the error? You need to specify it in your post to make us able to help you.